# XCode 15.2 displaying only one editor tab

Tags: xcode, editor, xcode15

Xcode 15.2 suddenly displays only a single open editor tab, whereas it normally displays all the open tabs in a horizontally scrolling list. Clicking the tab navigation arrows scrolls through the open tabs, but the tabs themselves no longer appear.

I'm guessing I caused this to happen with an accidental key combination, and I've looked through and tried several menus and settings.

What is the correct setting to display all open editor tabs?